# adding a callback to a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am trying to get jQuery to remove an element after it as run through a cycle of other functions, but following code block executes the `remove()` before it has run any of the `for` loop.

```
function waves(){
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
            wave(x);
    };
    $(x).remove();
}
```

Comment: What does Wave function do? Where is x defined. Can you post that?

Comment: this may be a really dumb question, but why do you have a semi-colon after the closing brace of the for-loop?

Comment: not sure, it doesn't cause an error.

Comment: It seems, that the `wave` function is some kind of async function. It's interesting to see the full code

Comment: @Alexander, this is just the way jQuery sequentially runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an if statement into your loop, that then calls your function.

```
function waves(){
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
            wave(x);
            if (i == 10) {
               callback();
            }
    };
}
function callback() {
    $(x).remove();
}
```